# Is there any solution in visual basic how to modify type dateTime to minccurs=0 in wsdl file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, wsdl

```
 Public class Example 
  public id as string
  public dateBirth As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
 End class
```

I have tried with nillable = true but still is not optional.

```
  <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="dateBirth " nillable="true" 
  type="s:dateTime"/>
```

The goal is this:

```
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dateBirth " type="s:dateTime"/>
```

Comment: A DataTime object in c# cannot be null!  The best you can do is the default constructor value of 1/1/01.

Comment: You don't read right. I am talking about visual basic (vb.net)

Comment: c# and vb.net use same Net library.